# What means R.Layout ? R.?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

i dont understand what is meant by R.layout or R.array in the following code, who describes
how to fill a spinner with drop-down menue with a array who has different countries as its elements:

```
adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.countries, androidx.appcompat.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

spinnerCountry.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The string Array with the name "countries" is loacated in the strings.xml file, in folder res -> values. Why is it necessary to use R.array to locate the country array and why can i not use findViewbyID?
And second question is why is in R.layout the spinner called support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item?
If i choose spinner on the Design tab via drag and drop theres only one spinner to choose.

Would be nice to have some help. Thank you.

I looked on the Developersite and searched the forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the values under `R` are generated at compile time. They're simply a list of `int` values with names likes `R.array.<name>` or `R.id.<name>` that can be used as identifiers for actual arrays, views, or whatever.

I think the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/spinner#Populate) explain what is happening quite well, but I'll explain in my own words anyway.

> Why is it necessary to use R.array to locate the country array and why can i not use findViewbyID?

A string array is not a `View`, so it wouldn't make sense to use `findViewById`. `findViewById` is a method that returns the `View` referenced by an `int` value defined in the `R.id` constants.

`R.array.countries` will just be an `int` value that references a string array. To get the `String[]` for that id, you would instead use `Resources::getStringArray(...)`. So, in the context of an Activity, you'd do `final String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries);`.

> why is in R.layout the spinner called support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item

`support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item` is the id for a layout. You should understand some of the different components of a spinner. There is:

- The `View` itself. There is only one of these, and it's what you see in the drag-and-drop option in the design/laout editor.
- The layout id for each row in the spinner when it is open. This is defined in the `layout` xml file referenced by `R.layout.simple_spinner_item`.
- The data used to populate each row. This is defined in the array referenced by `R.array.countries`.

Comment: wow. thank you for the explanation. i think now i see things a lot of clearer.